# late bind errors in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, compiler-errors, late-binding

I wonder if anyone has a solution or even a suggestion to the following problem.

I have created a Visual Studio forms application in VB using Visual Studio 2015 Community edition. The application works fine within Visual Studio in debug mode and it also works fine. when I run the compiled version on the same client.

However when I port the compiled code to a different client I start getting a large number of late bind errors. I am confident that these are false positives as in debug mode and in compiled mode on the initial client these errors are not present.

I can confirm that both clients have the same version of Net Framework installed under Windows 10.

Comment: Hi!
It would be useful if you post more details about the erros that appears on this specific client. Can you post some example?

Comment: Rafael thank you for the observation, but describing the context gets a little complicated and given that it only manifests as an issue on one client and not both it sounds more like an odd configuration error that I cannot seem to identify.

Comment: Sorry didn't finish ,  If it helps it relates to a function within a class of a user defined object stored in a collection of similar objects. This function uses one of the properties of the parent object as the key to reference and gather data from another object type of a different user defined class in another collection. A bit like a simple many-to-one database relationship lookup

Answer (score 0):

Doooh problem solved a silly referencing area for the default data file for the application